# Binary deserialization: get object data

Tags: c#, binary-deserialization

Is it possible to get data of the binary serialized object ( or list of othe same objects ) as it can be done in XML or soap. Please note, I have no idea about object structure ( private and public fields,etc)? By data of the binary serialized object I mean the values of all fields.

Comment: Of course it is possible. You have to deserialize your object graph, then you can do with it what you want. Please write more on what you want to achieve.

Comment: It *sounds* like you have a chunk of BF data, but don't have the class, and want to know what the data represents. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a stream.

```
            object yourData;
            var SerializeBinaryFileName = @"C:\Temp\binary.bf";

            using (Stream stream = File.Open(SerializeBinaryFileName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                yourData = bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
                stream.Close();
            }
```

Then you have your object graph in the yourData variable. 
You can read it as any other object graph can be read.

Comment: And will that work if file was serialized by Delphi for example?